# How do I efficiently write a large multiple table SELECT statement using a for loop?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The following SELECT statement is hideous, and I am struggling to make it work dynamically with a for-loop or groupby:

Current query:

```
SELECT  json_extract(_70.Shots,'$.total'), 
        json_extract(_73.Shots,'$.total'),
        json_extract(_76.Shots,'$.total')
        
FROM    ShootingRange_70 _70,
        ShootingRange_73 _73,
        ShootingRange_76 _76
    
WHERE _70.datetime LIKE '2020.08.03 23:07:%'
AND _70.datetime = _73.datetime
AND _70.datetime = _76.datetime;
```

I want to make the statement dynamic. Ideally, I am looking to make something syntactically similar to:

```
nums = [70,73,76];
SELECT  FOR num in nums:
        json_extract(num.Shots,'$.total')
        
FROM    FOR num in nums:
        `ShootingRange_`+num '_'+num

WHERE "_"+nums[0].datetime LIKE '2020.08.03 23:07:%'
AND 
    FOR num in nums:
    "_"+nums[0].datetime = "_"+num.datetime;
```

Comment: Try iterating through nums in Python and use your SQL statement each time. 
`nums = [70, 73, 76]`
`for num in nums:`
SQL Statement

Comment: Thanks @M-Chen-3. I'm actually executing this from a C++ environment. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Perhaps with a groupby or join using the `datetime` column?